# Display a line between each line break in a SSRS textbox

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, formatting, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report that has one very large textbox on it. Is there a simple way to display gridlines between each line break?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON7Ho.jpg

The only solution I can think of is to have 3 separate textboxes and use Len() to break up the text between the 3. This would be extremely tedious as I actually have 14 lines and they span the width of the page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text data into separate rows within your dataset using TSQL as described in the answer to this question: [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Instead of a comma, you're splitting on the linefeed character which you can reference as `char(10)`.

Note: You may need to strip out carriage return characters `char(13)`, too.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a way to do this without having to parse the text and the dataset I'm working with is extremely large, so I'd rather not use recursion. I'll give this a go though!

Comment: I understand SSRS 2008 adds support for some HTML and CSS. Maybe you could inject some `<P style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">` tags into your text by doing a replace on linefeed.